# MIN of Excel Subset of Range

Tags: arrays, excel, formula, min

I'm trying to find the min values of subsets of data in a pivot table.

The data is structured as such in a pivot table: column a (skill name), column b (supplier name), column c (hourly rate of each skill). i.e. SWE google $250, SWE oracle $214, and for another skill it would look like QA facebook $52, QA boston scientific $45, etc. I'm trying to find the min rate of each subset of skill/supplier, and have thus far only manually tried MIN(range of rates) for each skill/supplier subset. It's very manual as I have to change the range accordingly, and was wondering if there is a faster, more automated way to do it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, if your data is in range `A1:C5` your formula is:

```
=MIN(IF($A$1:$A$5=A1,$C$1:$C$5))
```

Take note that this is array formula and you apply it with `Ctrl+Shift+Enter`

Answer (score 0):

You could create a pivot table with row fields of skill name and supplier name and use MIN to summarise the hourly rate:
[image]